# Webscraping For Wordpress websites

Tags: python, wordpress, web-scraping, python-requests, response

I am scraping websites for my organization, using beautiful soup library in python. Using the request module. Till now I have scraped a lot of Wordpress websites but I'm facing an error for websites with .co and .ca domains (for the rest of websites I'm getting an entire response of the website (`response = self.html_getter.send_request_get_response(URL)`)

But for this .co/.ca website my code isn't getting any response, can anyone give me the solution? Thanks in advance 
this is the website I am
 trying to scrape "SEASONSANDSUPPERS.CA"

I am getting error **`HTTP Error 404: Not Found`**

Comment: Error 404 typically tells you that whatever page you are looking for is not there as requested i.e. bad URL (typo maybe?). If you manually copy the `.get` URL into a browser, what do you see?

Comment: website is getting opened. this is the website which I am trying to scrape "SEASONSANDSUPPERS.CA"

Comment: can you please guide me through this.?!

Comment: Please post the code you run for that call.

Comment: response = self.html_getter.send_request_get_response(url) Im using this command to get the html response(passing the SEASONSANDSUPPERS.CA in the place of url)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are omitting the "https://" part?
So when you pass the url, try the complete URL as https://seasonsandsuppers.ca

Comment: Not really, this is not the issue. there is one more website for which I am not able to get the HTML response of it https://www.sweetashoney.co. When I try to visit it initially it is asking me captcha for this website. It would be of great help if you could guide me through this.